# How to combine an Augmented reality with location based search (junaio) with an augmented reality with marker (vuforia)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, junaio

i had two apk, which one about augmented reality (junaio) and i want to combine it to apk from vuforia. i want to make an apk that can search a location and when  the location was found they can show some AR 3D with mark of the location.

examples i want to search X building, this apk will suggest that building in Y km, and when i found the x building it will give an augmented reality 3D with the x building is a marker

how to combine that ?

please help me how to combine it

Comment: this question has been already answered on the website. You should be reading the existing related posts before asking the same question over and over again :)

Comment: i already read it, and doesnt have a solution about. did you?

Answer (score 0):

For Vuforia, you can use Cloud Reco to get a location API of your choosing.

Junaio and Vuforia do the same thing, so I don't see the point in merging both. Junaio for web, Vuforia for Android/iOS.

To get you started on Cloud Reco for Vuforia, refer the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tksyhVlIMQ

Vuforia now allows us to upload objects into the target manager, whether it is an image or cylinder/box, or even a multiple dimension object.

Upload these into Vuforia Database (Database should be for cloud reco. If not, create a new database for it) and get the Client Keys.

Now you can import the Cloud reco prefab and add a text on top to augment.

Hope this helped. :)

Comment: thankyou jacob, but i still need to merging vuforia with location based search.

Comment: and i had one question when you said vuforia can upload object into the target manager , are they really use to make a building come to marker?

Comment: Could you please explain why you need Junaio then? As far as I can understand, your app required only one or the other.
And as answered, if you want location based search you need to be able to find yourself an API that does exactly that. Then you can go ahead and merge that API into Cloud Reco and voila! And yes, if you just see this link you'll see how you will be able to use any object at all. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXZF_VRBVk0

Comment: i already see that video , but that object is little like car, shoes,and toy. but how it works for a building?

Comment: 3D printed the features of the building, or Had a picture of all sides of the building from the Plan. Basic stuff really.